# jQuery dialog resize issue

Tags: jquery, user-interface

In my application I want to resize dialog box.Using jQuery UI Dialog i am able to do this. But the problem is, If the dialog box is resized beyond the browser boundary the button present at the bottom of dialog disappear (hides).

For better understanding visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form then click on "Create new user" to open dialog box. Drag this dialog box to the end of browser and then maximize it (resize).the buttons will disappears.My code is similar to the code given in the above link.

If any one knows solution for this please helps.

Answer (score 0):

set a maxwidth for the opened dialog.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ maxWidth: 600 });
```

Comment: I dont want to set max-width.

Answer (score 0):

depending on exactly what you mean, you could move the buttons out of the bottom div

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"> BUTTONS </div>
```

else i would expect that if you make the window bigger than the viewport what your are seeing is exactly what would happen